# Sinatra DataMapper adding data into sqlite db

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

So basically i'm trying to add some data from a form into a database using sinatra and datamapper. It works fine if I do it manually in the code but when i'm trying to add the data in the POST function that retrieves the form data, it does not work.
Suggestions? Advice?

```
class User
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :username , String
end


post '/form/' do
    username = params['username']
    @post = User.create(username: username)
end
```

I know for a fact that the username variable contains the string that I put in the form. So why isn't it showing up in the database? :(

Answer (score 0):

http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html

@post = User.create(:username      => "Name" )

Comment: That's what I did in the first place. The thing is that both ways work outside of the post function but not in it. Database is still empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay so apparently the action name "/form/" was the issue for some reason (i think). It works fine with only "/form".